# c++ coding to display paired bluetooth device

Tags: windows, visual-c++, bluetooth

I am trying to develop an .exe  to display the list of paired bluetooth devices. I used **BluetoothFindFirstDevice()** and **BluetoothFindNextDevice()** functions, but it displays only the available devices which are not paired. Kindly suggest me if their is any possible way.
I'm using visual studio 2008 in windows 7(32 bit) system.

Comment: What [search parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa362925(v=vs.85).aspx) are you passing to BlueoothFindFirstDevice?

Comment: I used **_BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_SEARCH_PARAMS** from BluetoothAPIs as the search parameter.

Comment: What I mean is have you read the [help](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa362925(v=vs.85).aspx) for that `BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_SEARCH_PARAMS` struct and have you tried experimenting with the different parameters to get different return results? For example the `fReturnRemembered` looks appropriate to your question.

Comment: Tank u for your information. Now I get a clear knowledge about 'BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_SEARCH_PARAMS' structure and I got my required output.